# Viewpoint sampling a 3D mesh model

Tags: 3d, rendering, render, visualization, mesh

I have a 3D mesh model stored in .ply format. I need to view this model from many different viewpoints, i.e. simulate putting the camera at a give [x,y,z] coordinate. Then I will need to save a 2D rendering of this image or better yet a pointcloud so that I can recover the surface normals visible at this viewpoint.

Does anyone know of any software (free or trial period) that will allow me to do this? Better yet, any ideas of how to do this programatically?

Thanks

For reference a sample mesh model can be downloaded from here: http://campar.in.tum.de/personal/hinterst/index/downloads!09384230443!/duck.zip

EDIT: Further information as requested

A bit of background about what I am trying to achieve:

I want to create a dataset of pose annotated images from a single 3D mesh. I'm trying to accomplish this by sampling viewpoints from each vertex on the upper hemisphere of an icosahedron that surrounds the mesh. This is the technique used in this [paper](http://campar.cs.tum.edu/pub/hinterstoisser2012accv/hinterstoisser2012accv.pdf) (Sec. 3.1.1), which I am trying to replicate

Comment: This question is not answerable in the current form. Care to tell us what you will be using the data for. Anyway, if you want a point cloud then there is really no reason for rendering it form many points in space. Unless you need some specific camera space dicing. All you need do do is sample points and then calculate normal for that point. As for image based approaches try blender.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks, I have updated the question with more inforamtion

Comment: Have you looked at [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)?

Comment: google it: http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=841&sid=ed963eaba40948b142c0dc194112c668

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the languages you are used to, THREE.js may be a good solution to quickly setup a scene and render your target from different points of view. A PLY loader is available [here](https://github.com/menway/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/PLYLoader.js).

Your best guess to getting a map of viewport-projected normals may be to create a shader and loading it in THREE.js. [This article](http://doc.minko.io/wiki/Create_A_Shader_Rendering_Per-pixel_Normals) should help you get there.